# Solving a System of two first first order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Below is my attempt to solve a problem from a text book on ODEs. My answer for $y$ does not match the book's answer. I would like to know where I went wrong or if the book is wrong.
Thanks,
Bob

Solve the following system of differential equations.
\begin{eqnarray*}
x' + y' - x - 3y &=& e^t \\
x' + y' + x &=& e^{3t} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Answer:
To solve this system of differential equations we will use the operator method.
\begin{eqnarray*}
(D-1)x + (D-3)y &=& e^t \\
(D+1)x + Dy &=& e^{3t} \\
(D+1)(D-1)x + (D+1)(D-3)y &=& (D+1)e^t = e^t + e^t = 2e^t \\
(D^2-1)x + (D^2-2D+3)y &=& 2e^t \\
(D-1)(D+1)x + D(D-1)y &=& (D-1)e^{3t} = 3e^{3t} - e^{3t} = 2e^{3t} \\
(D^2-1)x + D(D-1)y &=& 2e^{3t} \\
%
(D^2-2D+3)y - D(D-1)y &=& 2e^t - 2e^{3t} \\
(D^2-2D+3)y - (D^2-D)y &=& 2e^t - 2e^{3t} \\
(-D+3)y &=& 2e^t - 2e^{3t} \\
-\frac{dy}{dt} + 3y &=& 2e^t - 2e^{3t} \\
\frac{dy}{dt} - 3y &=& 2e^{3t} - 2e^t  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now we have a first order differential equation and we look for an integrating factor $I(x)$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
I(t) &=& e ^ { \int -3 \,\, dt } = e^ {-3t} \\
e^ {-3t} \frac{dy}{dt} - 3e^ {-3t}y &=& 2 - 2e^{-2t}  \\
D\left( e^ {-3t}y \right) &=& 2 - 2e^{-2t}  \\
e^ {-3t}y &=& 2t + e^{-2t} + c_0 \\
y &=& 2te^{3t} + e^t +c_0e^{3t} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
The books answer is:
\begin{eqnarray*}
x &=& ce^{-3t} + \frac{e^t}{4}  \\
y &=& -\frac{2e^{-3t}}{3} + \frac{e^{3t}}{3} - \frac{e^{t}}{2} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Didn't you already ask a similar question? Check by substitution which of the answers is the right one

Comment: Yes @YuriyS ...

Comment: Here the sign before $3y$ should be $+$: $$\frac{dy}{dt} - 3y = 2e^{3t} - 2e^t$$

Comment: You write $(D+1)(D-3)=(D^2-2D+3)$, but it should be $(D^2-2D-3)$, I think this was your mistake

Comment: @Moo wrote: Were there ICs? I do not know what he means by an IC.

Comment: @Moo if IC stands for initial conditions then the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This system is a simple one:

$$x' + y' - x - 3y = e^t \\
x' + y' + x = e^{3t}$$

Let's subtract the equations:

$$2x+3y=e^{3t}-e^t$$

So we immediately find:

$$x=-\frac{3}{2}y+\frac{1}{2} (e^{3t}-e^t)$$

$$x'=-\frac{3}{2}y'+\frac{1}{2} (3e^{3t}-e^t)$$

Substituting into the second equation:

$$-\frac{1}{2}y'+\frac{1}{2} (3e^{3t}-e^t)-\frac{3}{2}y+\frac{1}{2} (e^{3t}-e^t)=e^{3t}$$

Simplifying:

$$y'+3y=2(e^{3t}-e^t)$$

> $$y=C_1 e^{-3t}+\frac{1}{3}e^{3t}-\frac{1}{2}e^t$$

$$x=-\frac{3}{2}C_1 e^{-3t}-\frac{1}{2}e^{3t}+\frac{3}{4}e^t+\frac{1}{2} (e^{3t}-e^t)$$

> $$x=-\frac{3}{2}C_1 e^{-3t}+\frac{1}{4}e^{t}$$

Up to a constant (and a typo) the book answer is right.

---

In your solution you write: $(D+1)(D-3)=(D^2-2D+3)$, but it should be $(D^2-2D-3)$, I think this was your mistake.